# Ember property path convention w/ promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm wondering what Ember's convention is when faced with a property path (a property containing a dot) and one element is a promise. Its current behavior seems bug-ish... but perhaps there is a reason I don't understand.

To illustrate: if I have:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.Attr('string')
});
App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
    foo = DS.belongsTo('bar', { async: true })
});
```

Now given a Bar `bar`, and given related `Foo` exists,

```
bar.get('foo.name')
```

Will return the name of its `Foo` iff `bar.get('foo')` would return a fulfilled promise. Otherwise (when `bar.get('foo')` would return an *unfulfilled* promise), it returns "undefined".

Is this how things are supposed to work? If not -- I can report it; if so -- um... how come?

Comment: IMHO any property path in which components are promises should (always) return a promise which resolves to whatever is at the end of the path.

Comment: if `bar.get('foo')` won't return a fulfilled promise, `foo` could not get loaded. So it's consequent that `foo.bar` can't get loaded too because if there's no `foo`, there`s no `foo.bar` either. (or did I get you wrong?)

Comment: It could return an unfulfilled promise: there is a foo -- but not immediately available. (This happens even with the fixtureadapter, where everything is actually available, for some reason.) In this case  `bar.get('foo.name')` returns "undefined" for foo.name even if foo does exist and has a name.

Comment: a promise can only be rejected/resolved - if the promise is resolved, your object/data gets returned. so, if the promise is not resolved - how would JavaScript/the compiler know which `name` property you want to `get()`? the promise has to `resolve` if you want to get any property out of it (that's what the `then()` function is for... if you call any property/method on an unresolved promise, the value will of course be undefined... or I didn't understand your point again :(

Comment: That is why a path via a promise should again return a promise (IMO): it doesn't know and shouldn't try to guess until the promise is rejected or resolved. "undefined" means "it doesn't exist" not (the correct answer) "I don't yet know whether it exists -- sign up for an answer when one is available"